# Jquery Toggles too much after table

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am not the best Jquery dude around and today I was trying to achieve an easy toggle exercise. To toggle a section of a table using a trigger in a span...

I have a table were I would like to use a span inside the 'td' to trigger the toggle. I want jquery to toggle all rows under the current row until another row with class header is found...

Jquery code:

```
$('.meer').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('span.meer').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).parents().nextUntil('tr.header').toggle(100, function(){
    });
});
```

The code on the third line is the headbreaker for me. + I'm not sure about the first selector ('.meer') || ('span .meer')..

```
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95nWh/
```

The problem is that everything after the table gets display none after toggling...
Please check out the Fiddle

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the `.nextUntil` keeps going after leaving the table element. The solution is changing `$(this).parents().nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function () {});` to `$(this).parents().nextUntil('tr.header,div').slideToggle(100, function () {});`

http://jsfiddle.net/jg7UG/1/

EDIT: Had link wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$(this).parents()`, with no arguments. The `.parents()` function is intended to receive a selector as argument.
https://api.jquery.com/parents/

What you want to do is to find the direct `tr` ancestor of the span. There is `.closest()` for this.
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

So you must replace this:

```
$(this).parents().nextUntil('tr.header').toggle(100, function(){
 });
```

With this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
 });
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/YgKcN/